# Extend and re-assign vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to add custom props to v-card-title component of vuetify.
But, I want to still use  to call the vuetify component with my custom props, how can I do that?
I'm trying this, but doesn't succeed.

Example at codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/71nr1w3qvq

```
<template>
  <!-- How to add computed at VCardTitle? -->
</template>

<script>
import VCardTitle from "./somepath/VCardTitle";

export default {
  name: "App",
  props: ['variant'],
  extends: VCardTitle,
  computed: {
    addVariant: function() {
      if(this.variant === 'light') {
       return 'light-theme'
      }
      return 'dark-theme'
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: could you explain what you want exactly by doing that?

Comment: Vuetify give the component called v-card-title, but, I want to add a prop to customize that component and continue to call it by v-card-title.
I won't do a wrapper.

Comment: there's no way, you have to wrap it if you want to customize it

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I had to do wrapper to handle it =/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsx like this

```js
//App.js
export default {
  name : 'App',
  render(createElement){
    return createElement(
      'VCardTitle',
      'My title'
    )
  }
}
//if you want more information go to this documentation:
//https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to override the name of component of Vuetify and this causes a loop because the name is the same =/